# communication between Nodejs and iOS (libimobiledevice)

Tags: ios, node.js, libimobiledevice

I'm attempting to establish communication (messages/socket/tcp) between an iOS app (I can do either hybrid and Native app) and a macOS through USB (on the mac will be nodejs app the listen to messages)

I read on [libimobiledevice](https://libimobiledevice.org/) that it's possible to communicate from and to the IOS.

what will be the easiest way to send messages?